# Query regarding data manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'response': 'right'},
     {'fruit': 'apple',  'color': 'red', 'response': 'wrong'},
     {'fruit': 'pineapple',  'color': 'green',  'response': 'True' },
     {'fruit': 'pineapple',  'color': 'green',  'response': 'wrong' },
     {'fruit': 'orange',  'color': 'orange',  'response': 'wrong' }]



df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I want to remove duplicate combination of fruits and color observations where response = "wrong"

Comment: Result expected:
df = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'response': 'right'},
        {'fruit': 'pineapple',  'color': 'green',  'response': 'True' },
          {'fruit': 'orange',  'color': 'orange',  'response': 'wrong' }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort the column 'response'

```
df.sort_values(['response'], inplace=True)
```

**Output**

```
   color      fruit response 
2   green  pineapple     True
0     red      apple    right
1     red      apple    wrong
3   green  pineapple    wrong
4  orange     orange    wrong
```

Then you can remove duplicate values by using

```
df.drop_duplicates(['color','fruit'], inplace = True)
```

**Output**

```
    color      fruit response
2   green  pineapple     True
0     red      apple    right
4  orange     orange    wrong
```

You can convert your dataframe into the same order as it was before sorting by using-

```
df.sort_index(axis=0, inplace= True)
```

**Output**

```
    color      fruit response
0     red      apple    right
2   green  pineapple     True
4  orange     orange    wrong
```

This will give you the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'response': 'right'},
     {'fruit': 'apple',  'color': 'red', 'response': 'wrong'},
     {'fruit': 'pineapple',  'color': 'green',  'response': 'True' },
     {'fruit': 'pineapple',  'color': 'green',  'response': 'wrong' },
     {'fruit': 'orange',  'color': 'orange',  'response': 'wrong' }]

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df.drop_duplicates(['fruit','color']))
```

**Output:**

```
    color      fruit response
0     red      apple    right
2   green  pineapple     True
4  orange     orange    wrong
```

Comment: if i change the order of the observation then above syntax will remove right and keep 'wrong'

Comment: df = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'response': 'right'},
     {'fruit': 'apple',  'color': 'red', 'response': 'wrong'},
     {'fruit': 'pineapple',  'color': 'green',  'response': 'True' },
     {'fruit': 'pineapple',  'color': 'green',  'response': 'wrong' },
     {'fruit': 'orange',  'color': 'orange',  'response': 'wrong' },
{'fruit': 'orange',  'color': 'orange',  'response': 'right' }]

Comment: Result expected: df = [{'fruit': 'apple', 'color': 'red', 'response': 'right'}, {'fruit': 'pineapple', 'color': 'green', 'response': 'True' }, {'fruit': 'orange', 'color': 'orange', 'response': 'right' }]

Comment: Try: `df.drop_duplicates(['fruit','color'], keep ='first')` or `df.drop_duplicates(['fruit','color'], keep ='last')`

Comment: tried (df.drop_duplicates(['fruit','color'], keep ='last')) after sorting but of no use.
it seems like i have to hardcode labels alphabetically.which i wanted to avoid
In real dataset there is no order